# Why my subscribe function is printing an object instead of the result of the http request?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs

Why this code is printing this:

```
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
```

Instead of the array which is getting returned by my service?

```
    const trendingRentals: Observable<any> = this.rentalService.getRentals();
    const commonRentals: Observable<any> = this.rentalService.getCommonRentalsTest();
    const luxuryRentals: Observable<any> = this.rentalService.getLuxuryRentalsTest();

    const concatenation =  concat( [trendingRentals, commonRentals, luxuryRentals]);
    concatenation.subscribe(
      x => console.log(x)
    )
```

Comment: Thankyou so much!!! Im new to web development so I'm having trouble understanding Observables,Promises and async functions :C
Any resources recommended for a newbie like me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **concat** static operator here is accepting **Observable(s)** as parameter(s) not an **Array**.

If you are passing an Array of Observables will give you back the nested observables.

Read the *internet* for a more comprehensive answer and find [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1308) and [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/786) some references.

Answer (score 1):

The original code you had calls

```
concat([obs1, obs2, ..., obsN])
```

on a technical level, this is simply a case of providing the wrong argument to the concat function, as it expects

```
concat(obs1, obs2, ..., obsN)
```

as Andrew also pointed out. You can read more about rxjs functions on [learn-rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/)

To go into a tiny bit more depth: what concat does is return an observable from other observables. When concat is called upon execution, it executes each of the observables you put in, and waits until each one has completed in order before returning.

The Array [obs1, ..., obsN] is not an observable, hence the 'weird' response.

Answer (score 0):

I modified 
    `const concatenation =  concat( [trendingRentals, commonRentals, luxuryRentals]);`
for 
    `const concatenation =  concat( trendingRentals, commonRentals, luxuryRentals);`
Now it's working perfectly, however i dont understan why... Can someone explain to me what is happenning?